# MVC3 Url.Abs returns domain at Azure, not the CNAME record at domain registrar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I have a Windows Azure application at http://[some GUID].cloudapp.net.

I have used a CNAME record at GoDaddy to point mydomain.com to this application.  Everything works fine but one thing.  I send emails from this application and embed links to the site using

```
@Url.Abs(Url.Action("Action", "Controller"))
```

Url.Abs always prepends the http://[some GUID].cloudapp.net domain, not mydomain.com.  I haven't found an overload to this helper that lets me pull my domain name out of the web.config or something like that.  How do I tell MVC3 to use mydomain.com?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, because I don't see how the app could possibly know the .cloudapp.net domain. CNAMEs don't work that way... the app would only see "mydomain.com."

Are you sure your CNAME is set up correctly, and it's not just forwarding or "masking" or something?

Comment: No, these are outgoing URLs generated at the server.  The server thinks it is guid.cloudapp.net, so it uses that name.  Sure, the rest of the world sees mydomain.com, but Azure doesn't have that CNAME record, GoDaddy does.  I'm looking for some setting in Azure, or even a different call that will allow me to inject a different domain name.

Comment: What I'm telling you is that your web app doesn't know <guid>.cloudapp.net. The only API that you can call to even get that address is the Service Management API, and your web app couldn't call that without you giving it an API certificate, etc. So what I'm saying is, the string "<guid>.cloudapp.net" has to be coming from outside of your app. Typically, it would come in as the HOST header on a web request, but if you're using a CNAME, the value of the HOST header will always be the domain you browsed to (not what it's CNAME'd too).